# Trying to find a book from the 2000s geared towards young adult/teens

Tags: identification-request

I just remembered this book series that I read as a teen. I can’t remember the name of them and it’s killing me! I know this a long shot but here it goes:

It’s about a girl going to college (or it could also have been some sort of private high school that has dorms). Weird events start happening while she is there. It’s a series with maybe 3-4 books. She tries to solve the events with a friend I think?

I don’t get the impression these books were best sellers at the time but I could be wrong. Like I said I know it’s a long shot but I just had to try. Thanks!

Comment: Since you've found it, you should be able to mark your answer as accepted within a day.

Answer (score 1):

I found it! It was the Blue is for Nightmares series. Thought it might help someone else!

Comment: Hi! Could you please add details to this answer to confirm how it it the right one? Thanks.

Comment: It might also be useful to mention how you found it - did you just remember the title, or did some combination of search terms work? That could make it even more helpful for others reading this post :-)